# problema con foreign key

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

tengo dos tablas, una es viajes y la otra es rutas, lo que quiero hacer es que la tabla de viajes este relacionada con una foreign key hacia la de rutas pero mi duda es si es correcto también la tabla de ruta colocarle una foreign key hacia la tabla de viajes o esta no llevaría?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Una ruta siempre va a existir haya o no haya viajes, mientras que un viaje necesita rutas. Por lo mismo es que la llave foranea solo existe en la tabla viajes apuntando hacia rutas.

Ahora bien, es probable que un viaje tenga más de una ruta (no conozco la lógica de la aplicación específica). En ese caso, necesitas una tabla intermedia de rutas de viaje que tendrá una llave primaria compuesta tanto de la llave del viaje como la llave de la ruta (y tal vez el sentido o la fecha en caso de que el viaje dure varios días). Esta tabla tendrá llaves foraneas apuntando a la tabla de viajes y a la tabla de rutas. Esta tabla puede llamarse rutasViaje o DetallesViaje.